# Remove undefined index

Tags: php

None of the solutions in the other threads were clear. I need help removed the undefined message. The line of code that is causing it is this variable:

```
$ain = $_Get['AIN'];
```

Other threads mentioned using upset although I could not follow. I want to be able to pass a value in whether it is null or not.

Comment: We can't tell you much more then is said in other threads based on that one line. You can try to [edit] your question to provide more detail on what you tried/what didn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the existence of the array index before using it, and provide an alternative value to use in case it isn't set.

For example:

```
if(isset($_GET['AIN'])){
  //The value is set and you can use it
  $ain = $_GET['AIN'];
} else {
  //The value is not set, so you should provide a default value
  $ain = NULL;
}
```

Also note that the PHP language is *case sensitive*, so if you want to refer to HTTP GET parameters, you should use `$_GET`, because `$_Get` will *not* work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to reference the superglobal $_GET, you can use one of the following:

```
<?php
$ain = 'default';
if(isset($_GET['AIN']))
    $ain = $_GET['AIN'];
```

Or use the ternary:

```
<?php
$ain = isset($_GET['AIN']) ? $_GET['AIN'] : 'default';
```

Or the shortest with the null-coalescing operator:

```
<?php
$ain = $_GET['AIN'] ?? 'default';
```